# how can $r=\frac{1}{n^{\frac13}}$ be used to calculate the mean separation between electrons?

Tags: electrons, distance

Can $r=\frac{1}{n^{\frac13}}$ be used to calculate mean separation of electrons

suppose that Na which has BCC crystalline structure, each atom donate 1 electron to form metallic bonding

As it's BCC then for 1 cubic, 68% of its is atom so electron cloud can move freely in other 32%

However for Cu which also donate 1 electron but has FCC crystalline structure whose 74% of a cube is atom so electron can only move freely in other 26%

So how can the mean separation remain the same for all structure? Moreover $r=\frac{1}{n^{\frac13}}$ is for particle in a volume so it can be used for atom or molecule but in metallic bond, atom try to get close as possible as in ionic bond. In my book atoms are close that it touch each other so isn't that mean the separation is zero?

[image]

Can $r=\frac{1}{n^{\frac13}}$ use for 2 different type of particle which has different size ex: eletron and positive Na ion in a volume?

Answer (score 0):

If you have $N$ point particles in a volume $V$, i.e. the particle density is $n=N/V$. Then any particle has a volume $\frac{V}{N}=\frac{1}{n}$ for itself. Imagine dividing $V$ in $N$ little cubes and all cubes hold one particle, than the distance between a particle and its nearest neighbour is $\left(\frac{V}{N}\right)^{1/3}=\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{3}}}$, namely the length of the cube.

I imagine that this is how you get the formula you mentioned. It works obviously for valence electrons which are bound to atoms in a primitive cubic lattice. Where did you get the formula from and to which situations is it supposed to apply?